# HTML tag img's property onload does not work in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to detect if an image in html `<img>` tag loaded completely.

This is my code in the template of Angular2 component.

```
  <li *ngFor="let id of imagesId">
       <img width="300" src="{{imagesUrl[id]}}" 
            *ngIf="imagesUrl[id]"
            (onload)="loadOk(id)">
    <div *ngIf="!imagesLoadStatus[id]" class="loader"></div>
  </li>
```

This is my code in this component:

```
  loadOk(id: number) {
    this.imagesLoadStatus[id] = 1;
  }
```

Before loaded completely, all `imagesLoadStatus[id]` equal to `0`, and I want to change it to `1` by event `onload` when the whole image loaded completely.

But it does not work at all. How can I detect whether an image loaded completely or not in Angular2, Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(onload)="loadOk(id)">
```

should be

```
(load)="loadOk(id)">
```

There is no `onload` event, only a `load` event. `onload` is for JS to register an event listener, but it's not the events name which is required for Angulars event bindings.

Comment: It do works. I really confused about these `event` name. By the way, I want to ask where can I check all these event name and how to choose correct one to use?

Comment: They are all documented in the HTML spec. See for example `Events` in the left sidebar in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.
Angular supports `(foo)="bar($event)"` for every DOM event and every `@Output() foo;` of Angular components. For events from Angular components you have to check the source or docs of the component.

Comment: Hi, I want to ask you another question, just like I mentioned before, I want to hide the image until this image is loaded completely. But now I can see both `loader` and half loaded image. How can I hide the image until it is loaded completely? I add `*ngIf="imagesLoadStatus[id]"` to `img<>`, the image cannot be loaded any more.

Comment: You can add `[hidden]="imagesLoadStatus[id] != 1"` to `<img width="300" src="{{imagesUrl[id]}}"`, then it should be hidden while loading.

Comment: Big surprise for me! Thanks again!

Comment: `hidden` is a property https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden of HTML elements. Angular allows binding to properties, `@Input()`s of Angular components using `[foo]="value"` and to HTML attributes (standard and custom ones) using `[attr.foo]="value"`